# Fuzzy C-Means Clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am performing Fuzzy Clustering on some data. I first scaled the data frame so each variable has a mean of `0` and sd of `1.` Then I ran the `clValid` function from the package `clValid` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-iris[,-5] # I do not use iris, but to make reproducible
clust<-sapply(df,scale)
intvalid <- clValid(clust, 2:10, clMethods=c("fanny"),
                validation="internal", maxitems = 1000)
```

The results told me 4 would be the best number of clusters. Therefore I ran the `fanny` function from the `cluster` package as follows:

```
res.fanny <- fanny(clust, 4, metric='SqEuclidean')
res.fanny$coeff
res.fanny$k.crisp
df$fuzzy<-res.fanny$clustering
profile<-ddply(df,.(fuzzy),summarize,
           count=length(fuzzy))
```

However, in looking at the `profile`, I only have 3 clusters instead of 4. How is this possible? Should I go with 3 clusters than instead of 4? How do I explain this? I do not know how to re create my data because it is quite large. As anybody else encountered this before?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your problem; `profile` shows four clusters to me.

Comment: I also could not reproduce the problem, `profile` gives me four clusters as well.

Comment: I mean, like I said. I used iris in the code above as my dataset is quite large and impossiable to re-produce. So although you might not be able to re-produce it, I am curious to know if anybody has encountered this before in their own data as I asked in my question. Please read the question fully. I am wondering how this may have happened.

Comment: What does `res.fanny$k.crisp` return in your example?  Does it also return 3?

Comment: I get 3 when I do `res.fanny$k.crisp`

Comment: One guess, I can not confirm (as I don't have your data) is that clValid is returning a different value because you are using a different distance metric than the default. Could you check if you change your metric in `fanny` to Euclidean, do you get the same answer?

Comment: Also there is no way to grantee that the crisp clusters will match the results of the clValid formula.  You should be able to access the membership of each of the 4 clusters using `res.fanny$membership`.  Does that produce 4 clusters?

Comment: So when I look at the membership, each one is 25%..... However, is SqEuclidean the same as Euclidean distance for fanny, just slower? As in fanny with euclidean that is the same as doing C-Means Clustering correct?

Comment: It sounds like something is not working if all of your data is assigned 25% to each group.  Without seeing your data it is very difficult to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183912/discussion-between-jack-armstrong-and-ian-wesley).

Comment: @ian-wesley I tried to write a full story, do you have any comment or edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt at an answer, based on limited information and it may not fully address the questioners situation. It sounds like there may be other issues. In chat they indicated that they had encountered additional errors that I can not reproduce.  Fanny will calculate and assign items to "crisp" clusters, based on a metric.  It will also produce a matrix showing the fuzzy clustering assignment that may be accessed using `membership`.

The issue the questioner described can be recreated by increasing the `memb.exp` parameter using the iris data set.  Here is an example:

```
library(plyr)
library(clValid)
library(cluster)
df<-iris[,-5] # I do not use iris, but to make reproducible
clust<-sapply(df,scale)

res.fanny <- fanny(clust, 4, metric='SqEuclidean', memb.exp = 2)
```

Calling `res.fanny$k.crisp` shows that this produces 4 crisp clusters.

```
res.fanny14 <- fanny(clust, 4, metric='SqEuclidean', memb.exp = 14)
```

Calling `res.fanny14$k.crisp` shows that this produces 3 crisp clusters.

One can still access the membership of each of the 4 clusters using `res.fanny14$membership`.

If you have a good reason to think there should be 4 crisp clusters one could reduce the `memb.exp` parameter.  Which would tighten up the cluster assignments. Or if you are doing some sort of supervised learning, one procedure to tune this parameter would be to reserve some test data, do a hyperparameter grid search, then select the value that produces the best result on your preferred metric. However without knowing more about the task, the data, or what the questioner is trying to accomplish it is hard to suggest much more than this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I encourage to read the nice vignette of the [clValid package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v025i04/v25i04.pdf).
The R package `clValid` contains functions for validating the results of a cluster analysis. There are three main types of cluster validation measures available. One of this measure is the Dunn index, the ratio between observations not in the same cluster to the larger intra-cluster distance. I focus on Dunn index for simplicity. In general connectivity should be minimized, while both the Dunn index and the silhouette width should be maximized.
`clValid` creators explicitly refer to the `fanny` function of the `cluster` package in their documentation.

The `clValid` package is useful for running several algorithms/metrics across a prespecified sets of clustering.

```
library(dplyr)
library(clValid)
iris
table(iris$Species)
clust <- sapply(iris[, -5], scale)
```

In my code I need to increase the iteration for reaching convergence (maxit = 1500).
Results are obtained with summary function applied to the clValid object intvalid.
Seems that the optimal number of clusters is 2 (but here is not the main point).

```
 intvalid <- clValid(clust, 2:5, clMethods=c("fanny"), 
                    maxit = 1500,
                    validation="internal",
                    metric="euclidean")
 summary(intvalid)
```

The results from any method can be extracted from a `clValid` object for further analysis using the `clusters` method. Here the results from the 2 clusters solution are extracted(`hc$`2), with emphasis on the Dunnett coefficient (`hc$`2`$coeff`). Of course this results were related to the "euclidean" metric of the `clValid` call.

```
hc <- clusters(intvalid, "fanny")
hc$`2`$coeff
```

Now, I simply call `fanny` from `cluster` package using euclidean metric and 2 clusters. Results are completely overlapping with the previous step.

```
res.fanny <- fanny(clust, 2, metric='euclidean', maxit = 1500)
res.fanny$coeff
```

Now, we can look at the classification table

```
 table(hc$`2`$clustering, iris[,5])

    setosa versicolor virginica
  1     50          0         0
  2      0         50        50
```

and to the `profile`

```
df$fuzzy <- hc$`2`$clustering
profile <- ddply(df,.(fuzzy), summarize,
               count=length(fuzzy))
profile
  fuzzy count
1     1    50
2     2   100
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: As far as I can see there are more than one question. I edited the answer to help you. Would you like to explain what part of your question is not answered?

Comment: My question is clValid produces 4 clusters. But when I cluster with 4 clusters, the 4th cluster does not show. Why? Your answer is telling me how to run clValid, which as useful as it is, does not answer my question.

Comment: When you cluster with k=4 in the fanny call, you end up with 4 cluster and res.fanny$k.crisp give you back 4 as result. I ran your code and I got 4 after res.fanny$k.crisp.